# Why is the Image.Margin in a CollectionView template not creating visual space?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

We have a **ListView** bound to a **List** of objects of a type called **Trial**. Each **Trial** has a property, called **Pictures**, that is a **List** of objects of a type, **Picture**, that represents an image and some metadata. We are using a horizontal **CollectionView** within the **ListView** item template to display thumbnails of the images, if any. The problem is in getting a little space between the images. We've tried setting a **Margin** property value on the **Image** in the **CollectionView** item template, but the images are still appearing right next to each other as seen in the illustration.

This is the XAML describing the ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="trialsListView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding .}"
        ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
        HasUnevenRows="True">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout Padding="20">
          <Label
              Text="{Binding Prompt}"
              BackgroundColor="{Binding TrialType, Converter={StaticResource TrialTypeToColorConverter}}"
              Padding="5" />
          <Label Text="{Binding Response}" />
          <CollectionView
              BindingContext="{Binding Pictures}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding .}"
              ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
              HeightRequest="{Binding Count, Converter={StaticResource PicturesCountToHeightConverter}}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <Image
                    HeightRequest="80"
                    Source="{Binding PictureName, Converter={StaticResource PictureNameToImageSourceConverter}}"
                    Margin="10" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
          </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And this is an example of output (from an iOS device):

[image]

I suppose we can enclose the Image in a **Frame** or some layout, but that feels like a 90s web hack. Surely there is a right way to get some spacing without resorting to adding screen elements? What do I not yet understand here?

Comment: Margin applies to the spacing between adjacent elements, and the Image is the only element in the template.  Enclosing the image inside of a Frame or other container is probably the best approach.

Comment: Your explanation makes me feel better about framing it. Thanks

Comment: Well, StackLayout has no screen elements.

Comment: Sadly, framing it (or enslosing it in any layout) seems to be the only way.